# do all java mvc based frameworks require you to wire up each and every file in a config file?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

do all java mvc based frameworks require you to wire up each and every file in a config file?

like in .net you can create generic routes that map to things like:

controller/action/parameter

I'm currently reading up on spring, but haven't reach the MVC part yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring MVC allows this thing then `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` is active, for example, given config:

```
<beans ...>

<context:component-scan base-package="some.controllers" />

<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

</beans>
```

And controller implementation:

```
package some.controllers;

...

@Controller
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String hello() {
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public String bye() {
        ...
    }
}
```

URLs `/sample/hello` and `/sample/bye` will be mapped to the corresponding methods. 
For controller/action/parameter kind of mapping controller looks so:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello/{parameter}")
public String hello(@PathVariable("parameter") String parameter) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: ok that is more like it, very straight forward and way less xml to manage!

Answer (score 1):

Most of them, but not all. More precisely, have a look at [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/), a presentation framework that uses "convention over configuration" and allows near to zero configurations (no XML, no annotations).

Answer (score 0):

Most are transitioning to default mappings (based on naming conventions) and annotations.

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Comment: This is one example from the Struts 2 documentations (there are others): http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-annotation-example-1.html (Follow up: http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-annotations-example-1.html)

Comment: The Convention Plugin is actually directly inspired by the great principles implemented in Stripes.

Answer (score 0):

[JSF 2](http://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net), Sun's own MVC framework, doesn't require that thanks to the new annotations.

JSF is covered in [Java EE 6 tutorial part II chapters 4-9](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html). At IBM developerworks there's also a nice summary about getting rid of [XML configurations](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu1/index.html) with help of JSF 2 annotations.